# How to prove that ECB mode is not CPA secure?

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack, ecb

I am new to cryptography and I do not know how to prove the ECB mode is not chosen plaintext attack (CPA) secure.

Comment: **Hint:** request $m_1$ and $m_2$ from oracle? That is why we need probabilistic encryption.

Comment: Which definition(s) of chosen plaintext attack security do you know?